# php mailer sends multiple emails based on dynamically generated table

Tags: php

I have a products table that i want to send as email, but phpmailer sends every row as separate email. Variables are taken from opencart cart template file. 
Other than phpmailer sends multiple emails, everything works as expected.

Here's the code:

```
<?php foreach ($products as $product) { ?>
<?php
$statusMsg = '';
$msgClass = '';
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    // Get the submitted form data
    $product_name = $product['name'];
    $product_href = $product['href'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $telephone = $_POST['telephone'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];

    // Check whether submitted data is not empty
    if(!empty($email) && !empty($name) && !empty($telephone) && !empty($message)){

        if(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false){
            $statusMsg = 'valid mail.';
            $msgClass = 'errordiv';
        }else{
            // Recipient email
            $toEmail = 'email';
            $emailSubject = 'Inquiry '.$name;
            $htmlContent = '<h2>Inquiry configuration</h2>
                <table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <td><h4>configuration</h4><p></td>
                            <td><a href="'.$product['href'].'">'.$product['name'].'</a></p></td>
                            <td><h4>Name</h4><p>'.$name.'</p></td>
                            <td><h4>Email</h4><p>'.$email.'</p></td>
                            <td><h4>Telephone</h4><p>'.$telephone.'</p></td>
                            <td><h4>Message</h4><p>'.$message.'</p></td>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                <table>';

            // Set content-type header for sending HTML email
            $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\n";
            $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

            // Additional headers
            $headers .= 'From: '.$name.'<'.$email.'>'. "\r\n";

            // Send email
            if(mail($toEmail,$emailSubject,$htmlContent,$headers)){
                $statusMsg = 'OK';
                $msgClass = 'succdiv';
            }else{
                $statusMsg = 'OK';
                $msgClass = 'errordiv';
            }
        }
    }else{
        $statusMsg = 'ERR';
        $msgClass = 'errordiv';
    }
}
?>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: You're looping around the function that sends email, so of course it will send multiple messages. If you want to send the whole table as one message, build the message inside the loop, then send it once after the loop. Also, you're not using PHPMailer, just the standard PHP `mail()` function.

Comment: Tried to enclose the message into the loop, but it now the message is empty after the loop starts. Yes you are right, its standard php mail

Comment: This is all standard debugging and basic logic – follow the flow of your code and *check* (don't assume) what it's doing at each point, output debug info where it's useful and make sure it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Try your code change to this code:

```
       <?php
        $statusMsg = '';
        $msgClass = '';
        if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
            // Get the submitted form data

            $email = $_POST['email'];
            $name = $_POST['name'];
            $telephone = $_POST['telephone'];
            $message = $_POST['message'];

            // Check whether submitted data is not empty
            if(!empty($email) && !empty($name) && !empty($telephone) && !empty($message)){

                if(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false){
                    $statusMsg = 'valid mail.';
                    $msgClass = 'errordiv';
                }else{
                    // Recipient email
                    $toEmail = 'email';
                    $emailSubject = 'Inquiry '.$name;
                    $htmlContent = '<h2>Inquiry configuration</h2>
                        <table>
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><h4>configuration</h4></td>'; ?>
<?php  foreach ($products as $product) { ?>
 <td><p><a href="<?php echo $product['href']; ?>"><?php echo $product['name']; ?></a></p></td>
   <?php } ?>
                               <?php     '<td><h4>Name</h4><p>'.$name.'</p></td>
                                    <td><h4>Email</h4><p>'.$email.'</p></td>
                                    <td><h4>Telephone</h4><p>'.$telephone.'</p></td>
                                    <td><h4>Message</h4><p>'.$message.'</p></td>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                        <table>';

                    // Set content-type header for sending HTML email
                    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\n";
                    $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

                    // Additional headers
                    $headers .= 'From: '.$name.'<'.$email.'>'. "\r\n";

                    // Send email
                    if(mail($toEmail,$emailSubject,$htmlContent,$headers)){
                        $statusMsg = 'OK';
                        $msgClass = 'succdiv';
                    }else{
                        $statusMsg = 'OK';
                        $msgClass = 'errordiv';
                    }
                }
            }else{
                $statusMsg = 'ERR';
                $msgClass = 'errordiv';
            }
        }
        ?>
```

Comment: @VOODOO Sorry i have not checked. But the best way to use opencart php mailer and move all your request for that mail to the corresponding controller file.